# How can I create a loop in Python with i indices where i is itself a variable?

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I would like to create a for loop indexed by i where in each iteration another for loop with i indices (j0, j1, ..., j(i-1)) is executed. In pseudo-python, I want to create something like this:

```
for i in range(12):
    for j0, j1, j2, ..., j(i-1) in itertools.product(range(5), i):
        <do stuff with the j's>
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: do you mean by  itertools.product(range(5), repeat=i) ?

Comment: `for prod in itertools.product(range(5), [i])`?

Comment: `for i in range(x): for j in range(i): do stuff`?

Comment: Yes user, that's what I meant. And just to be clear, I would like to have i different indices in my second loop, each of which goes from 0 to 4. So I don't think Josh's solution works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(12):
    for j in itertools.product(range(5), repeat=i):
        # Made-up statement to exercise j
        print j[0], print j[i-1]
```

`j` is just a tuple, so you index it as necessary. There's no need to create separate names for each value in an element returned by `itertools.product`.

Comment: That's very simple, thanks. I had forgotten that your index could be a tuple.